# MS Excel calculation - nested operations order

Tags: excel, math

I'm facing this issue, where excel is not following maths rules correctly. Here is the formula

```
=((F11*4.4)-R11)/G11
```

here are the figures

```
F11 G11 R11
37  57  23.38
```

the result of the formula I expect is = 2.445964912

yet Excel calculate that formula to 3.266315789

by the maths logic the above formula needs to be calculated in the following steps:

```
1. (F11*4.4) = AA
2. (AA-R11) = BB
3. (BB/G11) = CC (in this case 2.445964912)
```

am I thinking wrongly or this logic should be put to Excel differently?

[image]

Comment: `=((37*4.4)-23.38)/57` is 2.44596 are you sure your using the correct cells?

Comment: @Alex K. of course i'm sure... that's why i'm confused as why i'm getting wrong result... i'll post pic here too

Comment: @Elen - Alex is right.  Something is not right on your sheet.

Comment: Well, R11 is -23.38, not 23.38: those numbers are not the same!

Comment: @Tim Williams - just added pic - may be i dont see obvious?..

Comment: @AlexK. His R11 value is negative, which is not what he gave us above, maybe he means to add the R11 column?

Comment: @Tim Williams - it doesn't matter whether it's positive or negative

Comment: As @TimWilliams says; `=((37*4.4)--23.38)/57` *is* 3.266 as `x--n` is `x+n`

Comment: @Tim Williams - sorry i meant the result doesn't matter + or -. but yes you are right! i forgot to make R column positive!! how stupid... thanks guys...

Answer (score 1):

You can check using "Formulas" >> "Evaluate Formula", the steps are:

- 37*4.4 = 162.8
- 162.8 - 23.38 = 139.42
- 139.42 / 57 = 2.445964912

If you want to remove the sign you can add the `ABS()` function:

```
=((F11*4.4)-ABS(R11))/G11
```

Answer (score -1):

If your numeric display format rounds off numbers, Excel will still retain the full-resolution number in the cells. When Excel evaluates formulas, it uses these full-resolution numbers stored in the cells, *not* the rounded numbers that show in the display, which can give you results different than you expect.

I was able to get a result very similar to the one in your image, and I believe that with experimentation it would be possible to duplicate your result exactly. I set the format of cells F11 and G11 to a number format with no decimal places. Then I set F11 to 37.49999 and G11 to 57.49999. All I can *see* in F11 and G11 is 37 and 57 due to the formatting in place.

To find out whether something like this is affecting your results, simply place the cursor in each of F11, G11, and R11 to see the actual value. You can also see the actual numeric values by setting the formatting on the cells to "General", which will work even if the values are generated by a formula.

Comment: The kind of error mentioned above can easily confuse Excel users with limited experience; I hope the post is helpful to someone.